Filter resetting back to most recent ad when changing page
I have an application that has a search page to search for job ads. The search page also has dynamic pagination so you switch pages when you search for ads. I recently added filtering and sorting to the page though and something is not worked as expected. The sorting is supposed to work utomatically to just display the newest ad results first on the search page (and it works just fine). But the issue stems from the filtering which is supposed to filter ads that have been added in the last 7 days. As of now, when you toggle the filtering with a checkbox, it does it's job by displaying ads added in the last 7 days.The problem though is that when you change the page to the next the filtering just resets back to the latest ads instead of continuing to the ads added before. The pagination pages, which are also supposed to be dynamic don't adapt to the filtering (which I haven't figured out yet but I would appreciate some help there too).
I tried moving the filtering logic to my fetching hook but it got a bit confusing. Ialso tried moving the ifltering logic to the Adspage component and noot getting the right resutls. I have also tried removing the sorting which could be interfering with the filtering. The last thing I tried was removing the offset and limit querys from the api url and only handle the pagination on the frontend but it didn't do much good either. I am missing something....
The service with the api:

export const getAds = async (
  searchText: string,
  offset: number,
  limit: number
): Promise<IJobSearchResponse> => {
  const response = await get<IJobSearchResponse>(
    `https://jobsearch.api.jobtechdev.se/search?q=${searchText}&offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`
  );
  return response;
};


This is where the pagination is handled:

import { DigiNavigationPagination } from "@digi/arbetsformedlingen-react";
import { DisplayAds } from "../components/DisplayAds";
import { SearchForm } from "../components/SearchForm";
import { useAds } from "../hooks/useAds";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DigiNavigationPaginationCustomEvent } from "@digi/arbetsformedlingen/dist/types/components";
import { SearchTextContext } from "../context/SearchTextContext";
import "../sass/pagination&search.scss";

export const AdsPage = () => {
  const [getAdData] = useAds();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(1);
  const { searchText } = useContext(SearchTextContext);
  const [totalAds, setTotalAds] = useState<number>(0);

  const limit = 10;

  const handlePageChange = (e: DigiNavigationPaginationCustomEvent<number>) => {
    const pageNumber = e.detail;
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    console.log(pageNumber);

    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      if (searchText.trim() !== "") {
        const offset = (currentPage - 1) * limit;
        try {
          const totalCount = await getAdData(searchText, offset, limit);
          setTotalAds(totalCount.totalCount);
          setTotalPages(Math.ceil(totalCount.totalCount / limit));
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    getData();
  }, [searchText, currentPage, getAdData]);

  return (
    <>
      <SearchForm getAdData={getAdData} />
      <section className="search-hits-section">
        <h3>{totalAds} sökträffar</h3>
        <p> | </p>
        <h3>{totalPages} antal sidor</h3>
      </section>
      <DisplayAds />

      <section className="pagination-section">
        <DigiNavigationPagination
          afTotalPages={totalPages}
          afInitActivePage={currentPage}
          onAfOnPageChange={handlePageChange}
          af-total-results={totalAds}
          af-current-result-start={currentPage}
          afResultName="annonser"
        ></DigiNavigationPagination>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

This is the hook for the getting the data:

import { useCallback, useContext } from "react";
import { JobAdsContext } from "../context/JobAdsContext";
import { getAds } from "../services/AdService";
import { IJobSearchResponse } from "../models/IJobSearchResponse";
import { IJobAd } from "../models/IJobAd";

interface GetAdDataResult {
  ads: IJobAd[];
  totalCount: number;
}

export const useAds = () => {
  const { setJobAds } = useContext(JobAdsContext);

  const getAdData = useCallback(
    async (
      searchText: string,
      offset: number,
      limit: number
    ): Promise<GetAdDataResult> => {
      try {
        const jobData: IJobSearchResponse = await getAds(
          searchText,
          offset,
          limit
        );
        setJobAds(jobData.hits);
        console.log("Data retrieved:", jobData);
        return {
          ads: jobData.hits,
          totalCount: jobData.total.value,
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        return {
          ads: [],
          totalCount: 0,
        };
      }
    },
    [setJobAds]
  );
  return [getAdData];
};


The component with filtering and sorting logic:

import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { JobAdsContext } from "../context/JobAdsContext";
import { DisplayAd } from "./DisplayAd";
import '../sass/adsList.scss'

export const DisplayAds = () => {
  const { jobAds } = useContext(JobAdsContext);
  const [sevenDaySpan, setSevenDaySpan] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const now =  new Date().getTime();
  const sevenDaysAgo = now - (7*24*60*60*1000);

  const filterAds = jobAds.filter(ad => {
    const publicationDate = new Date(ad.publication_date).getTime();
    
    return sevenDaySpan ?  publicationDate >= sevenDaysAgo :  true;
  }) 

   const sortedAds = filterAds.sort((a, b) => {

    const A = new Date(a.publication_date).getTime();
    
    const B = new Date(b.publication_date).getTime();

    return  B - A;

  });

  
  return (
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="senaste">Visa för de 7 senaste dagarna</label>
      <input id="senaste" type="checkbox"
      checked={sevenDaySpan}
      onChange={() => setSevenDaySpan(!sevenDaySpan)}
      />
      {jobAds.length > 0 ? (
        <ul className="adsList">
          {sortedAds.map((job) => (
            <DisplayAd key={job.id} jobAd={job}></DisplayAd>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <p>No job ads found.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};


